# Complex Linq-to-SQL where condition help

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, t-sql, where-clause

I have a perplexing SQL select statement (ugly) that I'm trying to write in LINQ. I'm working to get a single statment that will execute, not pre-selected data into lists that I have to send back to the server.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME ;
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME ;
SET @pStartDate = '20100501'
SET @pEndDate = '20100531'

SELECT r.company ,r.trandate ,r.currency ,r.account ,r.credit ,r.debit
FROM   dbo.Register r
INNER JOIN dbo.CompanyList c ON r.company = c.company
WHERE  
r.trandate BETWEEN @pStartDate AND @pEndDate
AND LEN(r.currency) > 0
AND ( 
    ( r.account = 'XXX-ZZZ' )
    OR
    ( LEFT(r.account, 3) IN ( SELECT LEFT(code, 3) FROM dbo.investments ))
    OR 
    ( r.account IN ( 
        SELECT account FROM dbo.CompanyInfo WHERE company = r.company
                   AND ( ( dateclosed IS NULL )
                   OR dateclosed >= @pStartDate) ) )
    )
```

This is an example that contains the problem code - a WHERE clause with a triple OR expression. I've tried using three different queries then concat() or union() which returns incorrect reccord count because a record may match multiple expressions. I'm going to try rearranging logic and create a new TSQL version that may help me find a solution in LINQ.

Ideas welcome.

Comment: Write out the LINQ alternative before you say the SQL version is perplexing and ugly :P

Comment: I might have missed it, but I don't see anywhere that you actually use your join on CompanyList...

Comment: The join on CompanyList is a restrictive join. The data is not as clean as it should be so I join to tables trying to make sure only good stuff comes back.

Comment: Ah. Cool. I'd have to check, but I think adding " AND r.company IN (SELECT company FROM CompanyList)" to the WHERE clause might be more performant, but it might be a wash...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since LINQ-to-SQL supports TSQL via [ExecuteQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx) - why re-write something that works? Complex queries may well **deserve** a bit of hand-cranking. I would just leave "as is", and simply substitute:

```
SET @pStartDate = {0}
SET @pEndDate = {1}
```

which will be injected when you call

```
var data = ctx.ExecuteQuery<RegisterQueryResult>(tsql, startDate, endDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure SubString will translate in Linq to SQL so your LEFT parts probably won't translate at all. In fact, I'm relatively certain they won't so Marc's solution is probably best if you simply want to get over the hump. That said, the following **might** work if you assume a context object has been created and you're mostly taking the defaults on table and column names.

```
var registers = from reg in context.Registers
                where reg.Trandate >= pStartDate && reg.Trandate <= pEndDate
                && ((reg.Account == regValue)
                    || ((from investment in context.Investments
                         select investment.Code.Substring(0,3)).Contains(reg.Account.Substring(0,3)))
                    || ((from cInfo in context.CompanyInfo
                         where cInfo.Company == reg.Company && ((cInfo.DateClosed == null) || cInfo.DateClosed.Value == pStartDate)
                        select cInfo.Account).Contains(reg.Account)))
                select New {reg.Company, reg.Trandate, reg.Currency, reg.Account, reg.Credit, reg.Debit};
```